# Swappiness setting ignored in systcl.conf

Tags: performance, swap

My Ubuntu 12.04 x64 on Dell XPS 15 with 8GB of RAM has been really sluggish.

After some searching I came across post about swappiness. I noticed that swappiness on my system was reported as 0 which means swapping should only start when memory is all used and yet is was actually acting much the same as when swappiness is 60.

I set swappiness to 10 using:

```
echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

and update `/etc/sysctl.conf` with:

```
vm.swappiness = 10
```

After rebooting I notice that swappiness is reported as 0 again with same sluggish performance. I ran echo `10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` and the performance improved remarkably.

I rebooted again and check swappiness, it was reported as 0 again.
I executed `sudo sysctl -p` and could see the values from `sysctl.conf` take effect.

It seems that the value from `/etc/sysctl.conf` is ignored on boot.

I have a notebook with Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit and I also applied the same configuration. On the notebook the changes do take effect as expected and remain after a reboot.

Has anyone come across this kind of problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is there a swap partition? Do you have reasons, other then the sluggishness, to believe that it's been running out of RAM?

Comment: There is a swap partition and the system just start using it long before running out of memory. The swappiness parameter configures how soon the kernel should do it. With a value of 100 it start swapping aggressively immediately. With a value of 0 it should only start swapping once all RAM is used.

Comment: The real problem is that a change to the configuration is ignored when the system boots. The second problem is that a value of 0 for swappiness seems to have the opposite effect.

Comment: @CorneilduPlessis The reason for this is because kworker will get stuck in a loop searching for swap that does not exist. Change swappiness to 30 and see if you don't have better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Start a terminal emulator and run

```
cd /etc/sysctl.d/
echo "vm.swappiness = 10" | sudo tee 60-memory-management.conf
sudo chmod 644 60-memory-management.conf
```

Reboot and check if the new values are in use with:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`
```

Comment: I tried this and still end up with swappiness = 0 after reboot.

    sudo sysctl -p

is only way that set swappiness to the correct value.

Comment: @CorneilduPlessis I had the same issue. `vm.swappiness` was set in `/etc/sysctl.conf`; changing the value there solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just bung the following in my /etc/rc.local

```
sysctl -w vm.swappiness=1 #Discourage swapping.
```

Basically, you can run this command: `sudo sysctl -w vm.swappiness=1` at any time to change the swappiness.. cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness gives 1 after this.